# getting /NaN/ in path

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i need to pass some path to a javascript function which it needs it, i'm working with wordpress so actually i'm using this.

Setting this code in the functions.php archive in my wordpress site..

```
wp_localize_script('custom', 'WPURLS', array( 'siteurl' => 
get_option('siteurl') ));
```

And calling it on my javascript archive like this.

```
 $(function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {



    $('#home').backstretch([
        +WPURLS.siteurl+"/images/home-bg-slideshow1.jpg",
        +WPURLS.siteurl+"/images/home-bg-slideshow2.jpg",
        +WPURLS.siteurl+"/images/home-bg-slideshow3.jpg",
        +WPURLS.siteurl+"/images/home-bg-slideshow4.jpg",
        ],  {duration: 5000, fade: 750});
    });
  })
```

The error:

localhost/wordpress/NaN/images/home-bg-slideshow2.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Please note the path...

/NaN/images/home-bg-slideshow4.jpg

if i do this on localhost it works because of reasons, but on website hosting it doesn't obviously!,

```
$('#home').backstretch([
        "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/includes/images/home-bg-slideshow1.jpg",
        "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/includes/images/home-bg-slideshow2.jpg",
        "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/includes/images/home-bg-slideshow3.jpg",
        "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/includes/images/home-bg-slideshow4.jpg",
        ],  {duration: 5000, fade: 750});
    });
  })
```

What can i do?

if i use 
local or global variable ->

```
var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
```

it doesn't works because it throws the same error as using WPURLS.siteurl , i will be glad if someone can help me with this

Comment: `+WPURLS.siteurl` this converts `WPURLS.siteurl` to a number. Just remove the `+`

Comment: NaN = not a number, so it's probably Fedrico's answer^

Comment: Removed the + before WPURLS and the error is this now : http://localhost/wordpress/images/home-bg-slideshow3.jpg 404 (Not Found) , the path should be similar to this: /wordpress/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/includes/images/home-bg-slideshow4.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

```
+WPURLS.siteurl
```

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) converts `WPURLS.siteurl` to a number, and it doesn't work as the content of the string isn't parseable as a number, giving you `NaN`.

For example, run this:

```js
console.log(+"hello");
```

Just remove the `+`.

Comment: WPURLS.siteurl+"/images/home-bg-slideshow1.jpg" Removed the + and still, please note if i remove the other + the string won't concatenate and won't run the entire app (tried anyway)

Comment: If it was not for your help, it would not have solved the problem, thanks